# The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

The following error occurs when I upload my app to App Store Connect:

The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value

'' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX)

What is the solution for this error?

Comment: Question need some screenshot or image of issue

Comment: @son got it exactly right! This solved it for me! I can't think of a more bizarre and unrelated error message resolved by accepting the new agreement in the developer portal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there might be a PLA (Program License Agreement) update here. You may want to open the developer program site and then accept it. I hope it will solve this issue.